# cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'int'

Tags: c#

I keep getting this error:

> cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'int'

This is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class LearningListScript : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 

        {
        List <string> myFavoritePonies= new List <string>();

        myFavoritePonies.Add ("Princess Cadence");
        myFavoritePonies.Add ("Fluttershy");
        myFavoritePonies.Add ("nightmaremoon");

        Debug.Log("This List has " + myFavoritePonies.Count + "ponies.");

        Debug.Log("This pony's name at index 1 is " + myFavoritePonies.Count [1]);
        Debug.Log("This pony's name at index 2 is " + myFavoritePonies.Count [2]);
        Debug.Log("This pony's name at index 0 is " + myFavoritePonies.Count [0]);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {        
    }
}
```

I'm following a text book but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `myFavoritePonies.Count [1]` should be `myFavoritePonies[1]` (and so on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to apply an array index to an integer (the count of the array), which is why you're getting this error. Just put the index after the array variable.

```
Debug.Log("This pony's name at index 1 is " + myFavoritePonies.Count [1]);
Debug.Log("This pony's name at index 2 is " + myFavoritePonies.Count [2]);
Debug.Log("This pony's name at index 0 is " + myFavoritePonies.Count [0]);
```

Should be

```
Debug.Log("This pony's name at index 1 is " + myFavoritePonies[1]);
Debug.Log("This pony's name at index 2 is " + myFavoritePonies[2]);
Debug.Log("This pony's name at index 0 is " + myFavoritePonies[0]);
```

Comment: You're welcome, but the other answer provides a better sources for you (plus he was faster) so you should accept that one!

Comment: Thanks, but keep in mind, @user3858703, you should accept the answer you find most accurate and complete. Speed *should* have nothing to do with it (though I admit it usually does). Once you get enough 25 rep or more, you can also upvote any answer you found useful, even if it's not the answer you accept.

Answer (score 2):

The [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3(v=vs.110).aspx) property returns the number of items in the list as an `int`. To get an item a a particular index, use the [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc(v=vs.110).aspx) (`[…]`) on the list itself:

```
Debug.Log("This pony's name at index 1 is " + myFavoritePonies[1]);
Debug.Log("This pony's name at index 2 is " + myFavoritePonies[2]);
Debug.Log("This pony's name at index 0 is " + myFavoritePonies[0]);
```